# can not prevent libgdx scene2d/ui/ Label from being semi-transparent

Tags: java, android, libgdx, label, scene2d

No matter what i do, labels are semi-transparent.
 The labels inside the table(`labelA,labelB,labelC`) are 0% transparent at first but as soon as you set their text by `labelA.setText("sometext");` they get half transparent like their brother `labelWarning`. `labelWarning` is half transparent all the time. I have tried to add it to stage alone without a group(`stage.addActor(labelWarning);`), change it's `a` by `labelWarning.getColor().a=1;` but no difference! looking forward to your helps

```
    Label.LabelStyle ls=new 
    Label.LabelStyle(screenGame.getFont(),Color.BROWN);
    Label labelA=new Label("700 metre",ls);
    Label labelB=new Label("700 metre",ls);
    Label labelC=new Label("1500 metre",ls);

    labelWarning=new Label("sd",ls);
    labelWarning.setWrap(true);
    labelWarning.setPosition(50,30);
    labelWarning.setWidth(500);
    labelWarning.setAlignment(Align.top);

    tableEPS=new Table();
    //tableEPS.debug();

    tableEPS.row();
    tableEPS.add(epgrass).pad(10f);
    tableEPS.add(epdesert).pad(10f);
    tableEPS.add(epsnow).pad(10f);
    tableEPS.row();
    tableEPS.add(labelA);
    tableEPS.add(labelB);
    tableEPS.add(labelC);
    tableEPS.row();


    tableEPS.setFillParent(true);
    tableEPS.pack();

    episodesGroup=new Group();
    episodesGroup.setSize(worldwidth,worldheight);
    episodesGroup.addActor(imagebgclouds);
    episodesGroup.addActor(backbutton);
    episodesGroup.addActor(tableEPS);
    episodesGroup.addActor(labelWarning);

    stage=new Stage(screenGame.getViewport());

    stage.addActor(episodesGroup);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you're changing the color via the LabelStyle instead of the Label itself. Since they all share the same LabelStyle instance, changing the style will affect all of them. Make sure you are changing the color or alpha by calling `label.setColor()`.

The color of the Label is multiplied by the color of the LabelStyle, so if you don't want to mess with the hue from the style, use `label.setColor(1,1,1, alpha)`.

Comment: didn't work, i even added `labelWarning.setColor(16, 14, 119, 1)`, before and after 
 `labelWarning.setText("sometext");` , created a different LabelStyle for `labelWarning`, still same, semi-transparent :(

Comment: The colors are on a 0-1 scale, not 0-255.

Comment: i did as you said and again didnt help.However i happened to find out that fonts that i draw by spriteBatch are semi-transparent too. But setting color as you said makes them opaque and i have to set rgba color after setting normal color for this to happen. `batch.begin(); font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        font.setColor(1,1,1,1.0f);
        font.draw(batch,"fps:"+(int)(1f/delta),0,50); batch.end();` I added the line `font.setColor(1,1,1,1.0f);` without this line this fps text is half transparent too  and  `labelWarning` is still same half transparent